# Accidentally entered the login window while working; is there another way to return to the regular desktop without typing in the password?

Tags: keyboard, password, login, login-screen

In other words, how do you exit the login window using shortcut keys or without inputting a password, or is avoiding this step not possible?

Comment: Having a workaround would make password-protected login kind of pointless, somehow :-)

Comment: If you don't know the password or the password entered is wrong, it was your colleague's Mac...

Comment: @nohillside which begs the question, why have a login window for the owner who's already logged in as the owner? I get the security reason, but it's inelegant imho.

Comment: @klanomath Nope, it's my macbook and I was experimenting with creating another admin account, and afterwards noticed my name on the menu bar, which I immediately wanted to get rid off. Clicked on "Login..." and entered the login window, leaving the work area active (audio was still playing). I got back to said work area easily as I knew the password. Despite the "If," your suspicion is off the mark, sorry.

Comment: @nicheese I forgot to add some smiley: this one  or another one !

Comment: As the answer below mentioned: if you use fast user switching, you can just click cancel. If you have your screensaver set to require a password to get back to work, or switch to the login screen in another way, you need your password. macOS is a Multi-user system, there can be several users logged in at once. So without password entry, how would access be protected?

Answer (score 2):

If you've accidentally switched to a different user, press ESC or click on Cancel to return to your desktop.

If instead you've landed in the login window, you need to select a user and type the password.

Comment: Yes, I landed in the login window. Some thought I was trying something shady, trying to get into someone else's machine; I should have clarified early on I am the owner and sole user of this macbook (I was able to get back to my running work window, fwiw.). I was just curious if there was another way I might not know about. If there's none aside from entering a password, that's fine.